# I have input of type datetime-local in html ,l should line to binding default valeu with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have input with type date-local in html ,i have a variable with defaut value, l should like to binding to the input value.

like this:

`Const today=momento.format("yyy-mm-dd")`

Html:
`< input type="date-local" valeu="{{today}}"/>`

but do not works!!

Comment: This question makes no sense you should try rewording it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I was look for the solution and i found this:
import {toDate,format} from 'date-fns-tz'
const event = new Date();
const parisDate = toDate(event.toISOString())
const pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"
const timeOutput = format(parisDate,pattern, { timeZone: 'UTC/GMT+1' }) 
this.datatime=timeOutput.slice(0, 16);
```